# How do I get lualatex+babel to use the "classic" TeX font families?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, babel, computer-modern

I'm getting (re)acquainted with babel and lualatex for multi-lingual documents. I know I can set individual font families with, say:

```
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
```

but how do I tell babel to "Use all of the classic TeX default font families for all font modes/styles" (including small caps, sans serif, etc.)? I thought I would tell it something having to do with "Computer Modern", but apparently there is no lualatex-usable font with a similar name.

Notes:

- I don't mind it being multiple commands.
- I use TeXLive 2019 (on Devuan Beowulf ~= Debian Buster).

Comment: latin modern (the default in lualatex) is essentially an updated computer moderm but there are other opentype computer modern eg Computer Modern Unicode and the new New Computer Modern. (you could use literally the traditional 7bit cmr10.tfm but that would be somewhat unusual choice as it would disable most luatex features, apart from Lua access)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm fine with any of those. But the question is mostly how do I tell luatex and babel to use one of them. And of course which one of them I should choose.

Comment: wel for latin modern just do nothing, that is the default

Comment: for CMU or NEWCM see Davislor's answer which is pretty comprehensive

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well, his answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: it isn't clear what you want to change, in what way does the default latin modern not meet the requirements?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm ok with using Latin Modern - but will it be used specifically when English is just one of several defined languages?

Comment: sorry I don't understand that comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I "define" english as a language for babel, does it know to use Latin Modern? I mean, english is just a string for it, it seems.

Comment: It will use latin modern unless you explicitly change fonts to use something else just as pdflatex uses computer modern unless you change fonts, there is no difference. choosing a language ideally has no effect on font choice at all. Obviously in legacy encodings for pdflatex  you need to switch encoding to LGR for Greek or T2 for Cyrillic etc but that's less of an issue with Unicode.

Answer (score 4):

Also define `\babelfont{sf}` and `\babelfont{tt}`.  For example:

```
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelfont{rm}
          {CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          {CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}
          {CMU Typewriter Text}
```

You will want to set most options with `\defaultfontfeatures` after `\usepackage{fontspec}` and before `\babelfont`, for example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[NewComputerModern]{
   UprightFont = {NewCM10-Regular},
   ItalicFont = {NewCM10-Italic},
   BoldFont = {NewCM10-Bold},
   BoldItalicFont = {NewCM10-BoldItalic},
   % Can define SizeFeatures to use NewCM08-* here.
   Extension = {.otf} }

\babelfont[english]{rm} % Language=Default suppresses a harmless warning.
          [Ligatures=Common, Language=Default]{NewComputerModern}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModern}

\begin{document}
Homer’s \textit{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Ὀδύσσεια}} begins,
“\foreignlanguage{greek}{ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς
μάλα πολλὰ πλάγχθη}.”
\end{document}
```

You can also define `rm`, `sf` and `tt` fonts per language, e.g.:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.o]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}
```

Comment: So, the second part of your answer is valid of course, not relevant to my question (I mean, I already knew that). About the first part: Will this influence the math fonts at all? Or are those independent of what I do with babelfont?

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work. With `\babelfont{rm}{CMU Serif}` I get: `Package fontspec Warning: Language 'English' not available for font 'CMUSerif' with script 'Latin'.`

Comment: And if I try `\defaultfontfeatures[NewComputerModern]{etc etc`, I get: `Undefined control sequence. \defaultfontfeatures`.

Comment: Finally, while the CMU Serif only gives a warning (so maybe I can still use it?), trying CMU Mono results in an actual error: `! Package fontspec Error: The font "NewComputerModern" cannot be found.`.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorry, the monospace Computer Modern Unicode font should have been Computer Modern Typewriter Text. Fixed now.

Comment: @einpoklum Make sure to `\usepackage{fontspec}` after `babel` and before `\defaultfontfeatures`. The command is from there.

Comment: Ok, trying this now.

Comment: Using fontspec right after babel still has the `\defaultfontfeatures` as an unknown control sequence, and the same goes for `\defaultfontfamily`. But `\defaultfontfeatures` is accepted.

Comment: @einpoklum The `\defaultfontfeatures` command is defined in `fontspec`, so make sure it’s properly installed? There is no `\defaultfontfamily`. I don’t see it anywhere, but if I did write that, it was an error. I’ve replaced that code snippet with a MWE that I tested in both LuaTeX and XeTeX.

Comment: It is installed: `Package: fontspec 2019/02/12 v2.7b Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: Hello @Davislor, I would be grateful if you could help me resolve my relevant issue here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618977/2288. Thanks in advance.