# fontspec/babel: Language 'Arabic' not available for font(fontspec) 'ScheherazadeNew' with script 'Arabic'

Tags: fonts, fontspec, babel, arabic

For the Arabic font [ScheherazadeNew](https://software.sil.org/scheherazade/), how to resolve this warning

> Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Arabic' not available for font(fontspec) 'ScheherazadeNew' with
> script 'Arabic'.

for the following document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures = {NoCommon, NoRare}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{ScheherazadeNew}[ Script = Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]

\usepackage[english, bidi = basic, layout = lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale = 1]{ScheherazadeNew}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}[Scale = 1]{ScheherazadeNew}

\begin{document}
    
\end{document}
```

Additionally, is it redundant to use `\newfontfamily\arabicfont` and `\babelfont[arabic]`? Or does each one have different functions?

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478487/54817

Comment: @SalimBou  different warning nature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That MWE looks mostly correct for LuaLaTeX.  You don.t need both `\babelfont` and `\arabicfont`: the first is for `babel`, which you’re using, and the second would be what you would use with `polyglossia`.

You do, however, want to add `\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}` rather than `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}`, to have `babel` correctly switch between your English and Arabic fonts.  It’s also likely that you want to scale the two fonts to the same height, rather than `Scale=1.0`.

The warning about the font not containing the language `Arabic` is normally harmless.  Fonts often don’t bother defining language tags that don’t change anything, like Greek for the Greek script or Hebrew for the Hebrew script.  In this case, the font designer didn’t bother declaring an Arabic language for the Arabic script, and making the file slightly bigger, because that’s already the default for the Arabic script.  You can suppress the message by loading a font with the `Language=Default` feature.  (In the same place where you currently have `Scale=1.0`.)

So this might work for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error if a glyph is missing from the current font
\usepackage[english, bidi = basic, layout = lists]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec} % For \defaultfontfeatures

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}

% Scheherazade New is available at:
% https://software.sil.org/scheherazade/
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Scale=1.0, Language=Default]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{ScheherazadeNew}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Language=Default]{Latin Modern Sans}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{ScheherazadeNew}

\begin{document}
Latin Modern Roman and
شهرزاد 
\end{document}
```

[image: Scheherazade New sample]

The main difference here is that it adds `Scale=1.0` to the main font only, and scales all other fonts in the document to the same x-height as `\defaultfontfeatures`.

You’ll still get a warning about using the default `tt` (monospace) font family.  If you need monospace Arabic,  Arabic Latin Modern Fixed is a good match for Latin Modern.

You might also have a look at New Computer Modern Book, another clone of Computer Modern that’s slightly thicker than Latin Modern.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. May I know how or where I can use the following in your answer? `\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
 \setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Latin Modern Math}`

Comment: You can add `unicode-math` either after or in place of `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Latin Modern Math is the default, so you could leave out `\setmathfont` in that case. However, I normally put `\setmathfont` immediately after my other font commands, so they’ll all be in one place.