# Persian letters do not work

Tags: xetex, unicode, xepersian, persian

I'm trying to use Persian letters. How can I add a Persian word now ? I do not follow the doc [here](https://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian/xepersian-doc.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\begin{document}
\begin{latin}
This is typeset by \textsf{\XePersian} package,\xepersianversion,
\xepersiandate.
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I use `above`, say, in the snippet below ?

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I want to write a word in Latin and let it translate to Persian.

Comment: "I do not follow the doc" Aren't you supposed to say "I follow the doc"?

Comment: Also... I think you just need to type in the content in the source code? What happens when you do that?

Comment: I think from your question, you don't want the `xepersian` package. You could try instead `arabxetex` or if you don't actually need a Unicode engine, `arabtex` with pdflatex.

Comment: A solution [like this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618977/fontspec-babel-language-arabic-not-available-for-fontfontspec-scheherazade/619003#619003) should work, changing `arabic` to `persian` and replacing the fonts with your fonts of choice.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write a word in Latin and let it translate to Persian.

That's not really what this package is about.

- The table you quoted, Table 1, lists the equivalent of some common LaTeX commands, but only in Persian script. The point is that you can use a command in the middle of a Persian text without changing your keyboard.
- The document, after calling `XePersian` will be in Persian mode by default. So type away and it will be typeset in Persian:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\begin{document}
\begin{latin}
This is typeset by \textsf{\XePersian} package,\xepersianversion,
\xepersiandate.
\end{latin}
متن خود را اینجا بنویسید.
\end{document}
```

- Of course, you need to have `XB Niloofar` font installed in your system.