# LuaLaTeX and Scheherazade New font

Tags: luatex, arabic

When using Scheherazade New font in LuaLaTeX, with a Arabic text containing vocalized letters, I get the following error message:

```
! error:  (linebreak): invalid list tail, probably missing glue
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This does not happen when I use Amiri font for example. I use the MWE provided in [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618977/fontspec-babel-language-arabic-not-available-for-fontfontspec-scheherazade/627549#627549) as a sample. I just changed the Arabic text to some vocalized text to produce the error message.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error if a glyph is missing from the current font
\usepackage[english, bidi = basic, layout = lists]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec} % For \defaultfontfeatures
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
% Scheherazade New is available at:
% https://software.sil.org/scheherazade/
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Scale=1.0, Language=Default]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Scheherazade New}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Language=Default]{Latin Modern Sans}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Scheherazade New}

\begin{document}
فَإِنْ لَمْ يَكُونَا كَذَلِكَ أَتَى بِمَا يَقْتَضِيهِ الْحَالُ وَهَذَا أَوْلَى
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce the error. Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: My TeXLive 2021 distribution on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 is up to date.

Comment: show your log-file.

Comment: Just an idea: try with the Harfbuzz renderer (ie, `[Language=Default, Renderer=Harfbuzz]`).

Comment: This made the trick! Thank you @JavierBezos

Comment: using harfbuzz with arabic is certainly a good idea, but your code shouldn't error without it, so really check if you have a current luaotfload.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do have luaotfload installed and up to date.